# Rating math quality via unit-in-the-last-place (ULP) differences

Tags: c, mathematics

**Goal**

Please review code in `fp.h` and `fp.c` to *index* and *compare* floating point values.

**Background**

C code can perform floating point math, yet how good is it?

One way is to test the floating point results of code at one precision against a greater, and supposedly more correct precision.
(This assumes the higher precision calculation is better, something not always true.  Will leave that issue for another day.)

How to rate differences?

**Indexing**

Consider all the floating point values assigned an index.

For `float`, `+0.0f` is indexed as 0, `+FLT_TRUE_MIN` is 1, ... `nextafterf(1.0f, 0.0f)` is integer `m-1`, `1.0f` is `m`, `nextafterf(1.0f, INFINITY)` in `m+1` ...  `FLOAT_MAX` is integer `n-1` and `INFINITY` is `n`.  Negative `float` go from `-0.0f` is 0, `-FLT_TRUE_MIN` is -1, ... `nextafterf(-1.0f, 0.0f)` is `-(m-1)`, `-1.0f` is `-m`, ...
Name this function `long fp_nthf(float x)`.

The index difference between successive `float` values is 1 and the math difference of these 2 values is akin to [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) (ULP).

**Comparing**

To compare between `float x1` and `double x0`,  assign to `x1` in a whole number index as above.  Assign `x0` to a like index that may include a fraction when `x0` is not exactly encodable as a `float`.  Example: a `double` value half way between `1.0` and `nextafterf(1.0f, INFINITY)` is `m + 0.5`.  Any `double` value far larger than `FLT_MAX` is indexed as `n`.  The compare result is a simple subtraction of the two indexes.
Name this `float fp_nth_difff(float x1_narrow, double x0_wide);`

**Testing**

To test this code,  I ran a few dozen pairs of `<math.h>` functions using the `float` version against the `double` version.  Tests, with an edit, can test all `float` or a select primary range of `float`.

Although both `float/double` and `double/long double` versions were written, posted test code only exercises `float/double`.

Many math function had a worst case differences of only a few ULP.  `roundf()/round()` had a 0.0 worst case (as expected) and `sqrtf()/sqrt()` had about 0.5 worst case (as expected).  Some function pairs had a surprising large difference.

---

**fp.h**

```
/*
 * fp.h
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 22, 2023
 *      Author: chux
 */

#ifndef FP_H_
#define FP_H_

/*
 * Return the ordinal of float x.
 * +0.0 returns 0, +FLT_TRUE_MIN returns +1, ... up to +FLT_MAX and +INFIITY.
 * -0.0 returns 0, -FLT_TRUE_MIN returns -1, ... down to -FLT_MAX and -INFIITY.
 */
long fp_nthf(float x);

/*
 * Return the ordinal of double x.
 * +0.0 returns 0, +DBL_TRUE_MIN returns +1, ... up to +DBL_MAX and +INFIITY.
 * -0.0 returns 0, -DBL_TRUE_MIN returns -1, ... down to -DBL_MAX and -INFIITY.
 */
long long fp_nth(double x);

/*
 * Return the unit in the last place (ULP) for a type float
 * from x1_narrow to x0_wide, possibly as a faction.
 */
float fp_nth_difff(float x1_narrow, double x0_wide);

/*
 * Return the unit in the last place (ULP) for a type double
 * from x1_narrow to x0_wide, possibly as a faction.
 */
double fp_nth_diff(double x1_narrow, long double x0_wide);

#endif /* FP_H_ */
```

**fp.c**

```
/*
 * fp.c
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 22, 2023
 *      Author: chux
 */

#include "fp.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int32_t), "Unexpected float size");
static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(int64_t), "Unexpected double size");

// nextafterf()-like macros only valid for positive finite float values.
#define NEXT_AFTERF_AS_U(x) \
  ((union { float d; int32_t i;}){.d = (x)}.i + 1)
#define NEXT_AFTERF_AS_FLT(x) \
  ((union { float d; int32_t i;}){.i = NEXT_AFTERF_AS_U(x)}.d)
// ULP from FLT_MAX to the next float as if float had more exponent range.
#define NEXT_AFTERF_FLT_MAX_ULP \
  ((NEXT_AFTERF_AS_FLT(FLT_MAX/FLT_RADIX) - FLT_MAX/FLT_RADIX)*FLT_RADIX)

// nextafter()-like macros only valid for positive finite double values.
#define NEXT_AFTER_AS_U(x) \
  ((union { double d; int64_t i;}){.d = (x)}.i + 1)
#define NEXT_AFTER_AS_DBL(x) \
  ((union { double d; int64_t i;}){.i = NEXT_AFTER_AS_U(x)}.d)
// ULP from DBL_MAX to the next double as if double had more exponent range.
#define NEXT_AFTER_DBL_MAX_ULP \
  ((NEXT_AFTER_AS_DBL(DBL_MAX/FLT_RADIX) - DBL_MAX/FLT_RADIX)*FLT_RADIX)

/*
 * See fp.h
 */
long fp_nthf(float x) {
  union {
    float x;
    int32_t i;
  } u = {.x = x};
  if (u.i < 0) {
    u.i = INT32_MIN - u.i;
  }
  return u.i;
}

/*
 * See fp.h
 * The below is _not_ highly portable code, yet works well for many implementations.
 */
long long fp_nth(double x) {
  union {
    double x;
    int64_t i;
  } u = {.x = x};
  if (u.i < 0) {
    u.i = INT64_MIN - u.i;
  }
  return u.i;
}

/*
 * See fp.h
 */
float fp_nth_difff(float x1_narrow, double x0_wide) {
  if (isnan(x0_wide) || isnan(x1_narrow)) {
    double x1_wide = x1_narrow;
    if (memcmp(&x1_wide, &x0_wide, sizeof x1_wide) == 0) {
      return 0.0;
    }
    return isnan(x0_wide) ? (float) x0_wide : x1_narrow;
  }
  float fraction;
  float x0_narrow;
  // Is x0_wide inside the `double` range such that
  // the "next" `double` value is also in range?
  if (fabs(x0_wide) < FLT_MAX) {
    // Find the difference between the high precision value
    // and its low precision form.
    float ulp;
    x0_narrow = (float) x0_wide;
    if (x0_wide > x0_narrow) {
      ulp = nextafterf(x0_narrow, FLT_MAX) - x0_narrow;
    } else {
      ulp = x0_narrow - nextafterf(x0_narrow, -FLT_MAX);
    }
    fraction = (float) ((x0_wide - x0_narrow) / ulp);
  } else {
    // Find the limited difference between the high precision value
    // and the range low maximum.
    if (x0_wide < 0 /* or signbit(y_wide) */) {
      x0_narrow = -FLT_MAX;
      fraction = (float) ((x0_wide - -FLT_MAX) / NEXT_AFTERF_FLT_MAX_ULP);
      if (fraction < -1.0) {
        fraction = -1.0;
      }
      x0_narrow = -FLT_MAX;
    } else {
      x0_narrow = +FLT_MAX;
      fraction = (float) ((x0_wide - +FLT_MAX) / NEXT_AFTERF_FLT_MAX_ULP);
      if (fraction > +1.0) {
        fraction = +1.0;
      }
    }
  }
  // Find the ordinals of narrow x1, x0.
  float diff;
  long ix1 = fp_nthf(x1_narrow);
  long ix0 = fp_nthf(x0_narrow);
  // Compute the ordinal difference
  if (ix1 > ix0) {
    diff = (float) ((unsigned long) ix1 - (unsigned long) ix0);
  } else {
    diff = -(float) ((unsigned long) ix0 - (unsigned long) ix1);
  }
  return diff - fraction;
}

/*
 * See fp.h
 */
double fp_nth_diff(double x1_narrow, long double x0_wide) {
  if (isnan(x0_wide) || isnan(x1_narrow)) {
    long double x1_wide = x1_narrow;
    if (memcmp(&x1_wide, &x0_wide, sizeof x1_wide) == 0) {
      return 0.0;
    }
    return isnan(x0_wide) ? (double) x0_wide : x1_narrow;
  }
  double fraction;
  double x0_narrow;
  // Is x0_wide inside the `double` range such that
  // the "next" `double` value is also in range?
  if (fabsl(x0_wide) < DBL_MAX) {
    // Find the difference between the high precision value
    // and its low precision form.
    double ulp;
    x0_narrow = (double) x0_wide;
    if (x0_wide > x0_narrow) {
      ulp = nextafter(x0_narrow, DBL_MAX) - x0_narrow;
    } else {
      ulp = x0_narrow - nextafter(x0_narrow, -DBL_MAX);
    }
    fraction = (double) ((x0_wide - x0_narrow) / ulp);
  } else {
    // Find the limited difference between the high precision value
    // and the range low maximum.
    if (x0_wide < 0 /* or signbit(y_wide) */) {
      x0_narrow = -DBL_MAX;
      fraction = (double) ((x0_wide - -DBL_MAX) / NEXT_AFTERF_FLT_MAX_ULP);
      if (fraction < -1.0) {
        fraction = -1.0;
      }
      x0_narrow = -DBL_MAX;
    } else {
      x0_narrow = +DBL_MAX;
      fraction = (double) ((x0_wide - +DBL_MAX) / NEXT_AFTERF_FLT_MAX_ULP);
      if (fraction > +1.0) {
        fraction = +1.0;
      }
    }
  }
  // Find the ordinals of narrow x1, x0.
  double diff;
  long long ix1 = fp_nth(x1_narrow);
  long long ix0 = fp_nth(x0_narrow);
  // Compute the ordinal difference
  if (ix1 > ix0) {
    diff = (double) ((unsigned long) ix1 - (unsigned long) ix0);
  } else {
    diff = -(double) ((unsigned long) ix0 - (unsigned long) ix1);
  }
  return diff - fraction;
}
```

**main.c**

```
/*
 * fp_function.c
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 23, 2023
 *      Author: chux
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "fp.h"

#define M_PIf 3.1415926535897932384626433832795f
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif
#define M_PIl 3.1415926535897932384626433832795L

// Compare function quality

typedef struct {
  const char *name;
  float (*f)(float x);
  double (*ref)(double x);
  long nan_count;
  struct {
    unsigned long long n;
    double sum;
    float x;
    float y;
    double ref;
    double diff;
  } error[2];
} statsf;

/*
 * Apply the x value to both a float and double version of a function
 * and determine the ULP difference.
 * Text result to determine minimum, maximum.
 */
static void test2f(statsf *st, float x) {
  double y_ref = st->ref(x);
  float y = st->f(x);
  float ulp = fp_nth_difff(y, y_ref);
  if (isnan(ulp)) {
    st->nan_count++;
    return;
  }
  bool index = signbit(ulp);
  st->error[index].sum += ulp;
  st->error[index].n++;
  if (index ? (ulp < st->error[1].diff) : (ulp > st->error[0].diff)) {
    st->error[index].diff = ulp;
    st->error[index].x = x;
    st->error[index].y = y;
    st->error[index].ref = y_ref;
  }
}

/*
 * Test many x values over a range steered by mode.
 * Report minimum, maximum and average ULP differences.
 * Also report name, not-a-number count, test time.
 */
static void test1f(const char *name, float (f)(float x), double (ref)(double),
    int mode, float x0, float x1) {
  time_t t0, t1;
  time(&t0);
  statsf st = {.name = name, .f = f, .ref = ref};
  puts(name);
  switch (mode) {
    case 0: {
      union {
        uint32_t u32;
        float f;
      } u = {.u32 = 0};
      do {
        test2f(&st, u.f);
        u.u32++;
      } while (u.u32 > 0);
      break;
    }
    default:
    case 1: {
      float x = x0;
      for (;;) {
        test2f(&st, x);
        if (x >= x1)
          break;
        x = nextafterf(x, INFINITY);
      }
      break;
    }
    case 2: {
      float x = -INFINITY;
      for (;;) {
        test2f(&st, x);
        if (x >= +INFINITY) {
          break;
        }
        x = nextafterf(x, INFINITY);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  time(&t1);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf(
        "%s(%- 16.6a /* %- 15.9g */) --> %- 16.6a, ref:% -22.13a  diff:% -16.6a % g\n", //
        st.name, st.error[i].x, st.error[i].x, st.error[i].y, st.error[i].ref,
        st.error[i].diff, st.error[i].diff);
  }

  printf(
      "%s: Differing NAN count: 0x%lX, Average difference (+ and -):%.6g, %.6g\n", //
      st.name, st.nan_count, //
      st.error[0].sum / (double) st.error[0].n, //
      st.error[1].sum / (double) st.error[1].n);
  printf("%s: Time: %.1f s, Coverage:%.3g%%\n", st.name, difftime(t1, t0),
      (double) (st.error[0].n + st.error[1].n) / pow(2, 32) * 100);
  double ulp = st.nan_count > 0;
  ulp = fmax(ulp, st.error[0].diff);
  ulp = fmax(ulp, 0.0 - st.error[1].diff);
  printf("%s: Quality: %.6g ulp (lower is better)\n", st.name, ulp);
  fflush(stdout);
}

/*
 * Test various float against double function versions to determine ULP differences.
 */
int main(void) {
  int mode = 0;
  float two_pif = 2 * M_PIf;
  test1f("acosf", acosf, acos, mode, 1 / 64.0f, 1.0f);
  test1f("acoshf", acoshf, acosh, mode, 1.0f, 16);
  test1f("asinf", asinf, asin, mode, 1 / 64.0f, 1.0f);
  test1f("asinhf", asinhf, asinh, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("atanf", atanf, atan, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("atanhf", atanhf, atanh, mode, 1.0f / 16, 1);
  test1f("cosf", cosf, cos, mode, two_pif / 64, two_pif);
  test1f("coshf", coshf, cosh, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("erff", erff, erf, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("erfcf", erfcf, erfc, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("expf", expf, exp, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("exp2f", exp2f, exp2, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("expm1f", expm1f, expm1, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("lgammaf", tgammaf, tgamma, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("logf", logf, log, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("log2f", log2f, log2, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("log10f", log10f, log10, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("roundf", roundf, round, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("sinf", sinf, sin, mode, two_pif / 64, two_pif);
  test1f("sinhf", sinhf, sinh, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("sqrtf", sqrtf, sqrt, mode, 1 / 64.0f, 64.0f);
  test1f("tanf", tanf, tan, mode, M_PIf / 64, two_pif);
  test1f("tanhf", tanhf, tanh, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  test1f("tgammaf", tgammaf, tgamma, mode, 1.0f / 16, 16);
  return 0;
}
```

**Sample test results**

```
acosf
acosf( 0x1.fdfbb0p-2   /*  0.498030424    */) -->  0x1.0caa18p+0  , ref: 0x1.0caa167374247p+0   diff: 0x1.8c8bdcp-1    0.774505
acosf( 0x1.f2c388p-2   /*  0.487074018    */) -->  0x1.0fe328p+0  , ref: 0x1.0fe329907c4e2p+0   diff:-0x1.907c4ep-1   -0.782198
acosf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.25534, -0.253564
acosf: Time: 8.0 s, Coverage:1.17%
acosf: Quality: 0.782198 ulp (lower is better)
acoshf
acoshf( 0x1.01cb98p+0   /*  1.00701284     */) -->  0x1.e4ce84p-4  , ref: 0x1.e4ce7fffe70f7p-4   diff: 0x1.00063cp+1    2.00019
acoshf( 0x1.01fbc2p+0   /*  1.00774777     */) -->  0x1.fd8bbap-4  , ref: 0x1.fd8bbdfd2e55ap-4   diff:-0x1.fe972ap+0   -1.99449
acoshf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.285198, -0.285124
acoshf: Time: 14.0 s, Coverage:0.781%
acoshf: Quality: 2.00019 ulp (lower is better)
asinf
asinf( 0x1.05e2c8p-1   /*  0.511495829    */) -->  0x1.12e7ccp-1  , ref: 0x1.12e7ca61470eap-1   diff: 0x1.9eb8f2p-1    0.810005
asinf( 0x1.048506p-1   /*  0.508827388    */) -->  0x1.115120p-1  , ref: 0x1.115121d9cc0b9p-1   diff:-0x1.d9cc0cp-1   -0.925385
asinf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.253222, -0.252497
asinf: Time: 7.0 s, Coverage:1.17%
asinf: Quality: 0.925385 ulp (lower is better)
asinhf
asinhf( 0x1.029578p-2   /*  0.252523303    */) -->  0x1.ffd2c4p-3  , ref: 0x1.ffd2c0851bb5ap-3   diff: 0x1.bd7224p+0    1.74002
asinhf( 0x1.094900p-1   /*  0.518135071    */) -->  0x1.fd4f64p-2  , ref: 0x1.fd4f678e6127ep-2   diff:-0x1.c73094p+0   -1.77808
asinhf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.310125, -0.309951
asinhf: Time: 28.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
asinhf: Quality: 1.77808 ulp (lower is better)
atanf
atanf( 0x1.63e4f6p-1   /*  0.695106208    */) -->  0x1.370198p-1  , ref: 0x1.3701964d2f55cp-1   diff: 0x1.b2d0aap-1    0.849248
atanf( 0x1.626772p-1   /*  0.692195475    */) -->  0x1.360000p-1  , ref: 0x1.360001b44773cp-1   diff:-0x1.b44774p-1   -0.852108
atanf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.252398, -0.254832
atanf: Time: 6.0 s, Coverage:1.17%
atanf: Quality: 0.852108 ulp (lower is better)
atanhf
atanhf( 0x1.ec2dd8p-4   /*  0.120160908    */) -->  0x1.ee9194p-4  , ref: 0x1.ee91908e2df16p-4   diff: 0x1.b8e908p+0    1.72231
atanhf( 0x1.c44ac4p-3   /*  0.220845729    */) -->  0x1.cbde40p-3  , ref: 0x1.cbde4369458c0p-3   diff:-0x1.b4a2c6p+0   -1.70561
atanhf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.328826, -0.328334
atanhf: Time: 5.0 s, Coverage:0.781%
atanhf: Quality: 1.72231 ulp (lower is better)
cosf
cosf( 0x1.3dc2e4p+2   /*  4.96502018     */) -->  0x1.ffe71ap-3  , ref: 0x1.ffe718e0fd5f5p-3   diff: 0x1.1f02a0p-1    0.560567
cosf( 0x1.d2cbc8p+0   /*  1.82342196     */) --> -0x1.ffe446p-3  , ref:-0x1.ffe444e10fc81p-3   diff:-0x1.1ef038p-1   -0.560426
cosf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.2503, -0.250278
cosf: Time: 5.0 s, Coverage:1.17%
cosf: Quality: 0.560567 ulp (lower is better)
coshf
coshf( 0x1.50a3c0p+0   /*  1.31499863     */) -->  0x1.ff21dcp+0  , ref: 0x1.ff21d9f3cbe4cp+0   diff: 0x1.061a0ep+0    1.02384
coshf( 0x1.4cefa6p+0   /*  1.30053174     */) -->  0x1.f8c908p+0  , ref: 0x1.f8c90a0b6a5edp+0   diff:-0x1.05b530p+0   -1.0223
coshf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.287201, -0.291299
coshf: Time: 8.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
coshf: Quality: 1.02384 ulp (lower is better)
erff
erff( 0x1.ac6212p-1   /*  0.836685717    */) -->  0x1.86ce10p-1  , ref: 0x1.86ce0e106cdcbp-1   diff: 0x1.ef9324p-1    0.967919
erff( 0x1.a88606p-1   /*  0.829147518    */) -->  0x1.84a0f0p-1  , ref: 0x1.84a0f1b3cd2d5p-1   diff:-0x1.b3cd2ep-1   -0.851175
erff: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.223033, -0.16874
erff: Time: 7.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
erff: Quality: 0.967919 ulp (lower is better)
erfcf
erfcf( 0x1.ffa0cep+2   /*  7.99418974     */) -->  0x1.f4030cp-97 , ref: 0x1.f4028c6183e9cp-97  diff: 0x1.fe79f0p+5    63.8095
erfcf( 0x1.0536dap+1   /*  2.04073644     */) -->  0x1.ff5894p-9  , ref: 0x1.ff589997a1a6ap-9   diff:-0x1.65e86ap+1   -2.79616
erfcf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.515177, -0.293407
erfcf: Time: 12.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
erfcf: Quality: 63.8095 ulp (lower is better)
expf
expf( 0x1.09546cp+1   /*  2.07288885     */) -->  0x1.fca7f0p+2  , ref: 0x1.fca7eeff2dc7cp+2   diff: 0x1.00d238p-1    0.501604
expf( 0x1.6232c2p+2   /*  5.53434801     */) -->  0x1.fa7c38p+7  , ref: 0x1.fa7c3900d3852p+7   diff:-0x1.00d384p-1   -0.501614
expf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.250292, -0.249759
expf: Time: 6.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
expf: Quality: 0.501614 ulp (lower is better)
exp2f
exp2f( 0x1.f50d16p-1   /*  0.978615463    */) -->  0x1.f87780p+0  , ref: 0x1.f8777eff2bdd4p+0   diff: 0x1.00d424p-1    0.501619
exp2f( 0x1.f8018ep-1   /*  0.984386861    */) -->  0x1.fa7d28p+0  , ref: 0x1.fa7d2900d2c88p+0   diff:-0x1.00d2c8p-1   -0.501608
exp2f: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.25023, -0.24981
exp2f: Time: 6.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
exp2f: Quality: 0.501619 ulp (lower is better)
expm1f
expm1f( 0x1.64373ap-2   /*  0.347866923    */) -->  0x1.aa0764p-2  , ref: 0x1.aa07626045420p-2   diff: 0x1.9fbabep-1    0.811972
expm1f( 0x1.738e06p-2   /*  0.362846464    */) -->  0x1.bfe9c0p-2  , ref: 0x1.bfe9c1a026f9ep-2   diff:-0x1.a026fap-1   -0.812797
expm1f: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.262575, -0.263275
expm1f: Time: 8.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
expm1f: Quality: 0.812797 ulp (lower is better)
lgammaf
lgammaf( 0x1.f5c116p+3   /*  15.6798201     */) -->  0x1.fc0ba0p+38 , ref: 0x1.fc0b293c32466p+38  diff: 0x1.db0f36p+5    59.3824
lgammaf( 0x1.ed99f2p+3   /*  15.4250422     */) -->  0x1.fd315cp+37 , ref: 0x1.fd31d2ac7efbcp+37  diff:-0x1.dab1fcp+5   -59.3369
lgammaf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):1.83998, -1.79289
lgammaf: Time: 11.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
lgammaf: Quality: 59.3824 ulp (lower is better)
logf
logf( 0x1.060106p+0   /*  1.02345312     */) -->  0x1.7bd1b2p-6  , ref: 0x1.7bd1b05d5b270p-6   diff: 0x1.a2a4d8p-1    0.817664
logf( 0x1.15ffb6p+0   /*  1.08593309     */) -->  0x1.51ac30p-4  , ref: 0x1.51ac31a276289p-4   diff:-0x1.a27628p-1   -0.817308
logf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.250147, -0.250404
logf: Time: 6.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
logf: Quality: 0.817664 ulp (lower is better)
log2f
log2f( 0x1.fff4fcp-1   /*  0.999915957    */) --> -0x1.fc9244p-14 , ref:-0x1.fc924580bdbe6p-14  diff: 0x1.80bdbep-1    0.751448
log2f( 0x1.0057f8p+0   /*  1.0013423      */) -->  0x1.fb4ed2p-10 , ref: 0x1.fb4ed380e6eb8p-10  diff:-0x1.80e6ecp-1   -0.751762
log2f: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.250287, -0.250191
log2f: Time: 6.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
log2f: Quality: 0.751762 ulp (lower is better)
log10f
log10f( 0x1.049648p+0   /*  1.01791811     */) -->  0x1.f97804p-8  , ref: 0x1.f977ffeae12a8p-8   diff: 0x1.0547b6p+1    2.04125
log10f( 0x1.f6e9d6p-1   /*  0.982252777    */) --> -0x1.fda7fap-8  , ref:-0x1.fda7f5df1f1aap-8   diff:-0x1.08383ap+1   -2.06422
log10f: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.321353, -0.314772
log10f: Time: 8.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
log10f: Quality: 2.06422 ulp (lower is better)
roundf
roundf( 0x0.000000p+0   /*  0              */) -->  0x0.000000p+0  , ref: 0x0.0000000000000p+0   diff: 0x0.000000p+0    0
roundf( 0x0.000000p+0   /*  0              */) -->  0x0.000000p+0  , ref: 0x0.0000000000000p+0   diff: 0x0.000000p+0    0
roundf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):-nan, 0
roundf: Time: 12.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
roundf: Quality: 0 ulp (lower is better)
sinf
sinf( 0x1.d520d6p+1   /*  3.66506457     */) --> -0x1.ffe332p-2  , ref:-0x1.ffe3331f09406p-2   diff: 0x1.1f0940p-1    0.560617
sinf( 0x1.0c05ccp-1   /*  0.523481727    */) -->  0x1.ffe56cp-2  , ref: 0x1.ffe56d1f13a9cp-2   diff:-0x1.1f13aap-1   -0.560697
sinf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.25468, -0.246516
sinf: Time: 5.0 s, Coverage:1.17%
sinf: Quality: 0.560697 ulp (lower is better)
sinhf
sinhf( 0x1.67da80p-1   /*  0.702838898    */) -->  0x1.86388cp-1  , ref: 0x1.8638885ba767ep-1   diff: 0x1.d22c4cp+0    1.82099
sinhf( 0x1.783ab6p-1   /*  0.734822929    */) -->  0x1.9b0380p-1  , ref: 0x1.9b0383a77a054p-1   diff:-0x1.d3bd02p+0   -1.8271
sinhf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.345111, -0.342198
sinhf: Time: 12.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
sinhf: Quality: 1.8271 ulp (lower is better)
sqrtf
sqrtf( 0x1.f82294p-6   /*  0.0307699628   */) -->  0x1.673f4cp-3  , ref: 0x1.673f4b0000028p-3   diff: 0x1.fffffcp-2    0.5
sqrtf( 0x1.000002p-6   /*  0.0156250019   */) -->  0x1.000000p-3  , ref: 0x1.000000ffffff8p-3   diff:-0x1.000000p-1   -0.5
sqrtf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.24994, -0.250049
sqrtf: Time: 34.0 s, Coverage:2.34%
sqrtf: Quality: 0.5 ulp (lower is better)
tanf
tanf( 0x1.563fe4p-1   /*  0.668456197    */) -->  0x1.945964p-1  , ref: 0x1.945962497d4b2p-1   diff: 0x1.b682b4p-1    0.856466
tanf( 0x1.921fc0p+0   /*  1.57079697     */) --> -0x1.7d9d3ep+20 , ref:-0x1.7d9d370b14023p+20  diff:-0x1.bd3b00p+1   -3.47836
tanf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.255053, -0.249743
tanf: Time: 5.0 s, Coverage:1.17%
tanf: Quality: 3.47836 ulp (lower is better)
tanhf
tanhf( 0x1.deddd4p-3   /*  0.233821541    */) -->  0x1.d6538cp-3  , ref: 0x1.d65387a6551e0p-3   diff: 0x1.166ab8p+1    2.17513
tanhf( 0x1.ddca18p-3   /*  0.233295619    */) -->  0x1.d54e4ap-3  , ref: 0x1.d54e4e608a402p-3   diff:-0x1.182290p+1   -2.18855
tanhf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):0.318596, -0.388396
tanhf: Time: 11.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
tanhf: Quality: 2.18855 ulp (lower is better)
tgammaf
tgammaf( 0x1.f5c116p+3   /*  15.6798201     */) -->  0x1.fc0ba0p+38 , ref: 0x1.fc0b293c32466p+38  diff: 0x1.db0f36p+5    59.3824
tgammaf( 0x1.ed99f2p+3   /*  15.4250422     */) -->  0x1.fd315cp+37 , ref: 0x1.fd31d2ac7efbcp+37  diff:-0x1.dab1fcp+5   -59.3369
tgammaf: Differing NAN count: 0x0, Average difference (+ and -):1.83998, -1.79289
tgammaf: Time: 11.0 s, Coverage:1.56%
tgammaf: Quality: 59.3824 ulp (lower is better)
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

## Get rid of the macros

All your macros can be replaced by regular functions or `static const` variables. Macros are hard to get right and thus are a source of bugs, and they often are harder to understand than a regular function or variable definition. Compilers will inline and optimize regular functions (provided their definition is visible) just as well as macros, so there is also almost never any performance benefit for macros.

I do like the immediately invoked unions, but I would not try to cram everything on a single line, and while type punning using `union`s is legal in C, it's not in C++, so if you want to make your code a bit more portable I'd just use `memcpy()`.

Consider this:

```
static double next_after_as_dbl(double x) {
    union {
        double d;
        int64_t i;
    } u;

    u.d = x;
    u.i++;
    return u.d;
}

static double next_after_dbl_max_ulp(double x) {
    return (next_after_as_dbl(x / FLT_RADIX) - DBL_MAX / FLT_RADIX) * FLT_RADIX;
}
```

And where you really have a compile-time constant you can write:

```
static const float M_PIf = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795f;
```

## Naming things

`x`, `x0`, `x1`, `y`, `d` and `i` are very short names, and their meaning is not the most common meaning for those letters, like `x`-coordinate and loop `i`ndex. I would try to find more meaningful words for them.

The same goes for the function names. `fp_nth_difff()`? This looks like a spelling mistake (an extra f) until you realize you follow the convention of C's math functions. Anyway, try pronouncing it like it's written and people will ask you if you are feeling alright. Maybe `ulp_difference_float()`?

Also, `fp_nthf()` returns something that is very different from the number of ULPs. Instead, it's the ordinal of the input, so maybe `ordinal_float()` is better?

C11 introduced [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic), so you could consider using that to create public `ulp_difference()` and `ordinal()` functions that automatically select the right `float` or `double` variants.

Create an `enum` for `mode` so you can name the three modes you have implemented.

## Add more high level comments to the code

Your comments explain very low level details of the algorithm to get the ULP difference, but this doesn't really help me see the big picture. For example, at the start of `fp_nth_difff()`, some explanation that you are first handling the case of one or both of the inputs being a NaN, and that the difference of two NaNs is a NaN itself unless they are bitwise identical NaNs.

Alternatively, split up the code into more functions that have clear, self-documenting names.

## Use a better way to measure time

On most platforms, `time()` only has a granularity of seconds. If you want to get something better and stay within C, then [`clock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) or [`timespec_get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get) might be better options, although they also come with limitations. The POSIX [`clock_gettime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html) function would be best if you can use it, particularly with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` so you don't have to worry about NTP adjustments, daylight savings time and leap seconds.

Comment: **All your macros can be replaced by regular functions.** --> Hmm, replacing _all_ is not great a practice.  What would you suggest to replace macros `FLT__MAX, INFINITY, M_PIf` with?  Perhaps you referring to `NEXT_AFTERF_FLT_MAX_ULP` and `NEXT_AFTER_DBL_MAX_ULP` to replace a constant with a function call.  I tied that and did not receive too bad a performance hit. Still not convinced it is that good an idea although it improve portability a bit.  Maybe you could provide a complete example?

Comment: Listing `fp_nth_difff()` does look amiss.  Listing it after `fp_nth_diff()` would have helped.  `diff` was pull out of the standard library `difftime()` which uses `x0`, `x1`.  `fp_ordinal()` is a good idea.

Comment: "it's not in C++" --> Portability to C++ or other languages is not a concern.  Portability to all C implementations is a concern.  “Create an enum for mod “ is minor and not part of the “Please review code in fp.h and fp.c to index and compare floating point values. “ goal.  Neither is `time()`, yet `clock()` would be a better metric.   POSIX `clock_gettime()` moves away from portability.

Comment: “x … meaning is not the most common meaning for those letters, like x-coordinate and loop index. “ → `x` is _the most common_ name of various single parameter `<math.h>` functions as used in the example code.  I used `x0`, `x1` instead of `x`, `y` to avoid confusion with math "y = f(x)".  Perhaps `x, y` still would have been better.

Comment: All in all, disagree with some, yet appreciate your insights and yes, more comments are warranted.

Comment: I've added an example for how the macros can be rewritten. Feel free to disagree! Some of what I say is just to get an alternative out there with its pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks for the example as it better illustrates your idea.  "Compilers will inline and optimize regular functions (provided their definition is visible) just as well as macros" is common yet not defined so.  It is that lack of certainty that led to macro usage. IAC, your idea is a reasonable approach - will conisder.